# Using More/Less over NFS share to view large files

Tags: linux

I have a Scientific Linux box that has an NFS share mounted where I have system logs being written.  When I try to run the `more` command on any log file that is over around 1GB on the share, it displays blank lines and when I try the `less` command, it says the file might not be a text file.  I can run either of these commands on smaller files.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: What does `wc -l your_file_name` tell  you?

Comment: Also, try `less -f -b16 -n` to force less to open without the warning, use a block size of 16k, and turn of line-numbering.

Comment: The less command opened the file and the first page contained @ symbols, I am able to tail the file and I see the most recent logs coming in

Comment: The wc -l came back with 8708358

Comment: (after long weekend). Did you try less with the `-f`, `-b`, and `-n` options?

Comment: Thanks, but it generates the same thing, pages of ^@'s